# site is loading fully zoomed in on mobile devices

Tags: responsive

my website is 980px wide. actually it is built on wordpress. My wordpress theme was initially responsive. Somehow i disabled its responsiveness. after that the website loads fine on desktop but it is loading 100% zoomed in on mobile and tablet devices. 
So my question is pretty simple. I just want to set the zoom level automatic for all types of devices.

Thanks

Comment: What is the theme?

Comment: Couldn't you use a meta tag of viewpoint?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee might be right, try to add < meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> into your header.php

Comment: I am pretty sure that viewport is the key too but if the site _used to be_ responsive as claimed that (probably) used to be in the header and I'd like to put it back the way it was if possible.

Comment: Why is this a WordPress question? Looks like a pure HTML/CSS issue.

Comment: It is meet gavernWP theme based on gavern framework. I removed all the code inside responsive.php , mobile.css and tablet.css. The site becomes unresponsive but it is loading fully zoomed in in the mobile devices and iphone.

Adding viewport meta tag didn't worked.

You can check my site here: www.bookelivery.in

Please help.